# Can't push an object into an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm building a game, and for my players I have a player class. This class defines things like their name, xpos, ypos etc. In my main game loop, I have to iterate over all of the current players (it's multiplayer) and update/draw them.

Problem is, I don't know how to store the players in the game class. I tried doing this in the game class:

```
this.players = [];
```

And then:

```
game.players.push(new player(name));
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

I always thought I could have objects as array elements, but apparently not.

Could someone advise a better way to do what I want?

Comment: Yes you can. The cause of the error is something else. Run the code in a good browser (Firefox, Chrome, ...) to view the error details...

Comment: Is `player` a function? FWIW, by convention, functions like that should start with a capital letter, `Player`.

Comment: @Dave Constructor functions, that is...

Comment: It was run in Chrome, and that was the error. I'll have to have a look elsewhere in the code then, but Chrome pointed me towards that line.

Comment: player is defined like this: var player = function(){}. But I thought that was how you define objects :P

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Yep, "functions like that". I should have been more precise.

Comment: @MartinHoe The above error message is from Chrome? If so, then try a different browser...

Comment: I wonder if maybe you have a `var player = new player(...);` somewhere? Then any later calls to `new player(...)` would be trying to use the object-`player` rather than the constructor-function `player`. (This is part of why constructor functions have their own naming convention: as other commenters have said, you should call it `Player`, not `player`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you defined the player constructor function?

There will need to be code somewhere that follows this format:

```
    function player(name) {
        this.name = name;

        // Initialise other members here.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a Game and Player class like this,

```
var Game = function() { this.players = []; }
var Player = function(name) { this.name = name; }
```

You can do

```
var game = new Game();
game.players.push(new Player("test"));
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. Like, literally character for character. It must be something else affecting the code and Chrome's giving me the wrong line, I'll take a hard look tomorrow.

Comment: @MartinHoe In that case, in `game.players.push(new player(name));` player should have an uppercase P

Answer (score 0):

The context of `this` is probably changing to something you don't expect.

In your class, be sure to check the correct value of `this`.  You probably need to use closures to ensure you are talking about your class.

Like this:

```
var MyClass = Class.extend({
  myMethod: function() {
    var self = this;
    $('button').click(function({
      //in here, this is different
      //so use self instead
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out guys. I already had a variable defined to player earlier on in my code in another JS file. For anyone else with this problem, check you don't have anything like

```
var player = new player();
```

before you try and do this.